# Render in HTML result of ajax call with Ruby / Sinatra

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra

I have a jquery which uses parameters to query the Plivo api.

```
$(".localsearch").click(function() {
        var country_iso = $("#local").val();
        var region = $("#region").val();
        var prefix = $("#prefix").val();
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/local/data",
        data: { 'country_iso' : country_iso,  'region' : region,  'prefix' : prefix },
        success: function(data){
            window.location.href = '/local'
        }
      });
});
```

The ruby code block receives the parameters and queries through the api

```
get '/local/data' do
      country_iso =  params[:country_iso]
      region = params[:region]
      prefix = params[:prefix]
      p = RestAPI.new(AUTH_ID, AUTH_TOKEN)
      params = {'country_iso' => country_iso, 'region' => region, 'prefix' => prefix, 'limit' => 1}
      warn params.inspect   
      response = p.get_number_group(params)
      obj = response.last
      puts obj["objects"][0]["stock"]
      puts obj["objects"][0]["region"]
      @stock = obj["objects"][0]["stock"]
      @region = obj["objects"][0]["region"]
      @prefix = obj["objects"][0]["prefix"]
      @voice_rate = obj["objects"][0]["voice_rate"]

      erb :local
end
```

The parameters are passed and the terminal console shows a successful result:

```
{"country_iso"=>"US", "region"=>"NY", "prefix"=>"646", "limit"=>1}
57  # = puts obj["objects"][0]["stock"]
New York, UNITED STATES # = puts obj["objects"][0]["region"]
```

My question is this: how can I "echo" the ressults on my local.erb page? Local.erb below:

```
<h2>Your search returned the following result</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="fixed">Stock:</span><span class="fixed"><%= @region %></span></li>
          <li><%= @region %></li>
          <li><%= @prefix %></li>
          <li><%= @voice_rate %></li>
          <li><input type="submit" class="buynumber" value="Buy this number" /></li>
          </ul>
```

The results are only printed in the terminal with puts .. and nothing appears on the local.erb page when the jquery redirects the user to local.erb.

Thank you for considering this!

Comment: what is the point of doing AJAX if you redirect when the call completes?

Comment: If I could render it on the same page (search.erb) that would be great. How can I do that?

Comment: return your values (`@region`, `@stock`, etc) from your `/local/data` as json, and then parse the response inside your `success` function (well, you do not even have t parse it because it is json) and put it into your page. you can use for example http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/json.html

Comment: thanks could you elaborate just a little further ...? If I knew how to do this I would not be asking. How do I parse the response inside my success function?

Comment: here is one of many tutorials that I found on the web: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-single-page-web-apps-with-sinatra-part-1/. It uses knockout, but you do not have to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@akonsu gives a good response. Don't redirect at the end of an AJAX call to a route.

There's also 2 ways to do this:

- Send some data, you get a response as an echo, which you then use to confirm and display
- Send some data, you get a response as an echo, which you then use to confirm, but you use the sent data to display.

You've got the sending of the data done.

#### Getting a response as an echo.

Change the last line of the `get '/local/data'` route to:

```
  halt 200, {stock: @stock, region: @region, prefix: @prefix, voice_rate: @voice_rate}.to_json
end
```

It's better to use `halt` than just leaving it as the last statement because you get to add a [status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success) as well, which is helpful when doing things other than GET.

If you still needed to render the route to a browser and not just an AJAX call you could do something like:

```
  if request.xhr? # XHR is the X in AJAX, so this is the AJAX call
    halt 200, {stock: @stock, region: @region, prefix: @prefix, voice_rate: @voice_rate}.to_json
  else # this would serve browsers, you could also filter by content type… YMMV
    erb :local
  end
end
```

In your AJAX request, add a couple of lines to make sure you request JSON (see [jQuery-ajax-settings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings))

```
$(".localsearch").click(function() {
    var country_iso = $("#local").val();
    var region = $("#region").val();
    var prefix = $("#prefix").val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/local/data",

    accepts: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",

    data: { 'country_iso' : country_iso,  'region' : region,  'prefix' : prefix },
    success: function(data){
        window.location.href = '/local'
        // this is the bit where you render stuff
    }
  });
```

});

#### Confirm the data is correct

I'll leave that to you. You could just check the status code and trust the rest, or you could use a checksum or hash of somekind… that's for you to decide and implement.

#### Displaying the response.

Add a div with id `search_echo_placeholder` (or whatever) to the search page, where you want the output to show.

In the javascript, do something like this:

```
display = function(data) {
  var stock, region, prefix, voice_rate, _i, _len, _ref;

  result = "";
  for (_i = 0, _len = data.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    _ref = data[_i], stock = _ref.stock, region = _ref.region, prefix = _ref.prefix, voice_rate = _ref.voice_rate;
    result += "<li>" + stock + "</li>";
    result += "<li>" + region + "</li>";
    result += "<li>" + prefix + "</li>";
    result += "<li>" + voice_rate + "</li>";
  }
  result = "<ul>" + result + "</ul>";
  return result;
};

// add this to the AJAX function
  dataFilter: display,
  success: function(result, status, xhr) {
    return [ $("#search_echo_placeholder").html(result) ];
  },
```

Something along those lines. I've liberally copy and pasted and made up bits so don't rely on this verbatim, it's there to give you an idea.

Comment: thank you for your incredibly thoughtful answer. I am working, now, on putting it all together but one additional problem has arisen in that the returned data (from the api call) is not coming back as "proper" json! I will keep plugging away, thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of the last several attempts, it does not work and I have been unable to debug it. I'll keep trying.

Comment: thanks for your massive effort and beautiful script. I will store it away for future sue in a different context. I think I am going to have to approach this particular problem in a different way as I still cannot get proper json back from the server.

Comment: @user1903663 No bother, just happy to try and be a help. What appears to be wrong with the JSON? Feel free to post it up.